# Change constraints for a button on another screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift

On the first and second screen I have 2 buttons, but on the third screen I should leave only one button, change the title for it and put it down, closer to the bottom of the view. Can’t figure out how to change button’s position if its constraints goes from storyboard.
OrangeButton is above, whiteButton is under it. They are arranged vertically. I use 3 instances of the same VC to show these buttons. On the 3rd instance I try to hide whiteButton which is under orange one, and orange Button should go down.

```
            if index == 2 {
                whiteButton.isHidden = true
                orangeButton.setTitle("Start”, for: .normal)
                //here I have to set new constraints for orangeButton
            } else {
                whiteButton.isHidden = false
                orangeButton.setTitle("Next”, for: .normal)
            }
```

Comment: You need to provide a more complete description of your setup and what you are trying to do. Are "first and second screen" different instances of the same view controller? Are your `whiteButton` and `orangeButton` arranged vertically, and with `orangeButton` above `whiteButton`?

Comment: (Edit your question to provide the extra info. Don't comment on my comments. Other readers of the thread should be able to read your question and know what you are asking without having to read a whole series of questions and answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want to do is adjust the spacing to be even with different numbers of buttons, stack views are awesome. Put your buttons in a stack view. Set up the spacing between items to the desired amount. Hide the ones you don't want and the stack view shifts the remaining items to space them out correcly.

If that's not what you're asking update your question to describe what you **are** trying to do.

Comment: cool advice! thnx) I think I should try using stack view for changing position of the button

Comment: It isn't obvious from the docs, but stack views respond to hiding/un-hiding items by removing/adding them to the stack and adjusting the spacing to compensate. It makes them very powerful and easy to use.

Comment: But before presenting the third instance, setting new constraints for the second button that will be near bottom would be also easy.

Comment: Sure, manipulating constraints is another way to do it. @Imran0001, do you want to edit your question to show how you would change the constraints (And remove the code that moves the button to a different VC)? Having answers that provide multiple approaches could be useful.

Comment: @Ducan C, I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing previous constraints of **orangeButton**

```
if indx == 1 { // It is for first screen
      let VC = yourViewControlarClass()
      self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
}else if indx == 2 { // It is for second screen
      let VC = yourViewControlarClass()
      self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
}else if indx == 3 { // It is for third screen which have only orange button bottom of the view
      let VC = yourViewControlarClass()
      VC.whiteButton.isHidden = true
      VC.orangeButton.removeFromSuperView() // for clear all constraint of orangeButton
      VC.orangeButton.frame = CGrect(x: 100, y: 600, width: 200, height: 60) // Giving new position & frame for orangeButton, you can change x,y,height,width as per your needs
      VC.orangeButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
      VC.view.addSubView(orangeButton) // adding orangeButton again for that have new constraint
      self.present(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to move a button from one view controller to another. Based on the code posted, it sounds like the first, second, and 3rd screens are instances of the same view controller.

Comment: @DuncanC you are right, they are instances of one vc

Comment: Okay, then I think your question needs more description. If you can provide pictures of the VC then it is better.

Comment: lmran0001, you should update your answer to explain exactly how to update the contraints, as that approach would work also (although since the OP clarified that they are using 3 separate instances of the same VC, you should get rid of the code in your answer that moves the button to a different view controller.) If you provide a clear, valid alternate solution I will certainly up-vote it.

Comment: I am not moving the button to different view controller, I am just giving new constraint for orangeButton in third instance. Please check the update.